# Using qsort() for stable sort?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I was trying to solve a problem in a online judge system: https://acm.cs.nthu.edu.tw/problem/11519/
It takes an integer n, followed with n lines of name and grade.
the problem is to sort them out by grades using a stable sort algorithm.
I use qsort() and giving the person's order in the compar() to stabilize the qsort(). Here is my code:

```
class People{
    public:
        char name[11];
        int grade;
        int order;
        void print(){ printf("%s %d\n", name, grade); }
};

int compar(const void *a, const void *b){
    People *A = (People*)a;
    People *B = (People*)b;
    if(A->grade > B->grade) return 1;
    else if(A->grade < B->grade) return -1;
    else if(A->order > B->order) return 1;
    else if(A->order < B->order) return -1;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    People *p = new People[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        scanf("%s %d", p[i].name, &p[i].grade);
        p[i].order = i;
    }
    qsort(p, n, sizeof(People), compar);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        p[i].print();
    }
}
```

in all of my test cases, it works without any problem, but the online judge keeps giving my submits four WAs(wrong answer). Can someone give me some clues about this? Many thanks!

Comment: If you want a stable sort, the C++ standard library calls it `std::stable_sort`

Comment: @StoryTeller Okay, I'll take it a look. However, I still want to know why did my implementation failed...

Comment: @StoryTeller but I've made it stable using the variable "order". if the grades are the same, compar() will compare the unique order to decide the order.

Comment: @Patricius You can't control that with this method, qsort is not stable, period.

Comment: You don't know what the implementation of `qsort` does across all standard library versions. Your added check may mess up it's guarantees. Plus there's also the problem of your compare function missing a return statement. Just write a proper strict weak ordering for your items, and use `std::stable_sort`

Comment: @StoryTeller Thanks, I'll try it!

Comment: The online judge may also be specifying names that include whitespace which your input approach will not cope with.

Comment: Don't use qsort in C++, it's a C function with a broken interface and no type safety.

Comment: Sigh. Yes, `qsort` is not stable: it makes no guarantees about the relative order of elements that **compare equal**. That **doesn't mean** that this approach won't work: explicitly giving an order to elements that would otherwise compare equal works just fine, because they **no longer compare equal**. `qsort` is not the villain here. I suspect a stupid grading algorithm that says `qsort` is the wrong answer.

Comment: @storyteller: OP's solution to making qsort stable is completely valid and indeed recommended by several textbooks. It is not the best C++ solution, to be sure, but your argument against it is totally unfounded.

Comment: @rici - Then you obviously completely misunderstood my argument.

Comment: @storyteller: qsort works with compare functions which compare more than one field, or any other comparison function which provides appropriate order guarantees, which OP's function does (aside from the bug noted by @paxdiablo). The manner in which the `order` attribute is computed is irrelevant to the implementation of qsort.

Comment: @rici - the bug noted by paxdiablo was added in an edit following a similar back and forth. And is my whole point. So you did miss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ends up that I missed a line in the description:

> The input includes multiple test cases. In each test case, the first line contains one integer N.

After several approaches, I got it passed  with the following code:

```
class People{
    public:
        char name[11];
        int grade;
        int order;
        void print(){
            printf("%s %d\n", name, grade);
        }
};

int compar(const void *a, const void *b){
    People *A = (People*)a;
    People *B = (People*)b;
    if(A->grade > B->grade) return 1;
    else if(A->grade < B->grade) return -1;
    else if(A->order > B->order) return 1;
    else if(A->order < B->order) return -1;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    int n;
    while(scanf("%d", &n)!=EOF){
        People *p = new People[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            scanf("%s %d", p[i].name, &p[i].grade);
            p[i].order = i;
        }
        qsort(p, n, sizeof(People), compar);
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            p[i].print();
        }
        delete[] p;
    }
}
```

std::stable_sort just works, However, it received TLE(Time Limit Exceeded),and the cin/cout causes TLE, too. So that's the reason I stick with printf/scanf.

Thanks everyone for answering this question! :)

Answer (score 6):

There is actually nothing wrong with your *intent* in the comparison function, it's a perfectly valid solution to use original ordering to turn an unstable sort into a stable one.

So, why it's being rejected, I cannot tell for sure, at least without having access to the test data being used.

It's *possible* that the names may contain spaces which will screw up your input method but (1) that doesn't seem to be indicated by the test description; and (2) it would make the input much more difficult, at least for the level the assignment seems aimed at.

However, though you may consider it unlikely, there *is* the possibility that the sorting algorithm may at some point compare an object with itself. This means it will return some arbitrary value since you assume they will always be different, given the added `order` checking.

You should probably cater for that since the one rule you're meant to follow in the comparison function is consistency and that, if `a > b` then `b < a`. So, *two* rules, really :-)

In addition, one thing I *would* suggest is to minimise your use of the legacy-C stuff like `printf` and `scanf` where C++ provides better facilities.

To that end, I believe you'd be better off with:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

struct People {
    char name[11];
    int grade;
    int order;
    void print() { std::cout << name << " " << grade << std::endl; }
};

int compar(const void *a, const void *b) {
    People *A = (People*)a;
    People *B = (People*)b;

    // Use grade if different.

    if (A->grade > B->grade) return 1;
    if (A->grade < B->grade) return -1;

    // Otherwise, use order, unique in different objects.

    if (A->order > B->order) return 1;
    if (A->order < B->order) return -1;

    // But cater for the possibility you may compare an object with itself.

    return 0;
}

int main() {
    int n;
    std::cin >> n;

    People *p = new People[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        std::cin >> p[i].name >> p[i].grade;
        p[i].order = i;
    }

    qsort(p, n, sizeof(People), compar);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        p[i].print();
    }
}
```

You might also even want to consider moving away from the legacy-C `qsort` since C++ provides stable sort built in, specifically the `stable_sort` found in `<algorithm>`.

Comment: Actually I've rewrited the code with vector and std::stable_sort but still got rejected. I might try to rewrite it with proper space handling. Thank you!