# qsort() in array of structure in C

Tags: c, qsort

I am trying to sort the array of structure which takes 20 inputs and sort them using C's standard library function qsort() but not getting proper sorted output.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#pragma pack(1)
struct player{
    char name[4];
    short age;
    short match;
    float average;
};
#pragma pack()
int comp(const void *p,const void *q){
    float *a=(float*)p;
    float *b=(float*)q;
    if(*b-*a>0)return 1;
    if(*b-*a<0)return 1;
    if(*b-*a==0)return 0;
}
int main(){
    struct player list[20];
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        scanf("%s",list[i].name);       
        scanf("%hu %hu %f",&list[i].age,&list[i].match,&list[i].average);
    }
    qsort((void*)list,20,sizeof(struct player),comp);
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        printf("%2.2f %10s %4hu %4hu\n",list[i].average,list[i].name,list[i].age,list[i].match);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

one may use the following test case to check there output.

```
aaa 21  22  34
qsd 33  21  44
qqq 1   2   55.2
www 33  22  12.2
ewe 22  11  13.3
qaz 22  33  12.33
aaa 21  22  34
qsd 33  21  44
qqq 1   2   54.2
www 33  22  12.2
eee 22  11  16.3
qaz 22  33  18.33
aaa 21  22  34
qsd 33  21  49
qqq 1   2   52.2
www 33  22  12.2
eee 22  11  10.3
qaz 22  33  11.33
eee 22  11  14.3
qaz 22  33  11.33
```

Comment: Why your `comp` is trying to interpret the passed pointers as `float*`?

Comment: `const void *p` does not point to `float` but to the whole `struct` element of the array. So the `comp` function can first cast the arguments to the correct type, and then compare members of the `struct`s.

Comment: your "a>b" and "a<b" cases both return the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Use a compare function like this:

```
int comp(const void *p, const void *q) {
  struct player *p1 = (player*)p;
  struct player *p2 = (player*)q;

  if (p1->average > p2->average) return 1;
  if (p1->average < p2->average) return -1;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not replace `if`s with `return p1->average - p2->average`? More concise and is the norm for comparison functions

Comment: @JonathanLam because that can overflow. It's typical, but faulty.

Comment: Not (only) that. The difference can be less than one, but then it is cast to `int`

Comment: @JonathanLam think twice, that can't be true, a utopia, to say the least... :)

Answer (score 1):

Your custom comparison method should look like this:

```
int comp(const void *p, const void *q) {
  struct player *a = (struct player*)p;
  struct player *b = (struct player*)q;

  if(b->average > a->average)
    return 1;
  else if (b->average < a->average)
    return -1;
  else
    return 0;
}
```

As @EugeneSh. and @WeatherVane commented, the parameters of that method are pointers to structs - for example the first element of your array will be pointed by `p` and the second by `q` at a certain comparison.

So, you first need to cast to a pointer to the struct, and then use its field to perform the actual comparison.

Now the comparison has a logical flaw as @Gereon and I commented: It returns 1 in the less AND in the greater case, which is surely not what you want. Return 1 in one case, and -1, for example, in the other case.

As for the `return 0;` case, it's good as it is, ensuring a [stable sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135394/using-qsort-for-stable-sort).

Tip: Do not be tempted to use `return p1->average - p2->average`, as typically illustrated in the ref's [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/qsort/), since you are dealing with `float`s, and the least thing you need is a numerical instability, since it can overflow. Moreover, the difference can be less than one, but then it is cast to `int`.

Comment: @WeatherVane we just practiced the paradigm of maieutics, introduced by Socrates 25 centuries ago.. Thanks guys (+EugeneSh.), you helped me improve my answer!

Comment: @EugeneSh. well there is the infinity representation, but if the values are very small, their difference might be `0.0` when it is not. Integers don't have that, so best to use a foolproof method all the time.

Comment: @WeatherVane No argument here :)