# Any stable sorting function in standard C libraries?

Tags: c, sorting

I notice that `<stdlib.h>` only includes `qsort` which is not stable. Therefore I cannot sort a composite data structure along different columns.

Is there any standard (POSIX/C11) and stable sorting algorithms in C?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but you might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135394/using-qsort-for-stable-sort) interesting.

Comment: I am confused by the title of your question.  You are asking about the C standard library not about the C language, which is different.

Comment: @JoelFan Unless you're a language lawyer, or dealing with non-hosted implementations, the distinction is rarely significant.

Comment: @Barmar I didn't get your point

Comment: @nowox In most contexts the distinction between the standard library and the language itself is not important, so JoelFan's comment is not really helpful.

Comment: @Barmar.... if you say so... I sure would not hire someone who didn't know the difference

Comment: @JoelFan Unless you're doing kernel programming, why would the difference matter? Does anyone really care that `printf()` isn't part of the language, but is just a library function? You can rely on it being there just as much as `if` and `while`.

Comment: @Barmar, there may not be many situations where "it makes a difference" to know such things, but it's hard to be a good developer when you don't understand "what's really going on" in general.  It's similar to not knowing the difference between the heap and the stack or thinking that there's such a thing as a "JSON object".  Sure it usually "doesn't matter", but good developers know these things.

Comment: @JoelFan I'd consider it an "expert programmer" thing -- I'm sure you can do just fine as a competent programmer without knowing these details.

Answer (score 0):

The C standard library contains only one sort function, which is `qsort`, but this function
does not sort elements in a stable manner.

https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Array-Sort-Function.html

So the answer is simple: There is no stable sorting function in the C standard library.

Answer (score 0):

There are no stable sorting functions in the C Standard. `qsort` does not always use the Quick Sort algorithm and some implementations might be stable but in general `qsort` is not stable.

Many Unix platforms provide a generic implementation of `mergesort`, which is stable as documented in this [BSD man page](https://man.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mergesort&sektion=3) and this [Linux one](https://linux.die.net/man/3/mergesort).

If `mergesort` is not available on your target platform, you can use [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort), which is stable, very efficient and has a portable reference [implementation](https://github.com/patperry/timsort/tree/master) in C. Timsort is the standard sorting algorithm in Java, Swift and Rust.

Note that it is easy to use a non stable `qsort` to implement a stable sort using an array of pointers:

- allocate and populate an array of pointers to the original array
- sort this array using an ancillary sorting function modelled after this:

  ```
  struct S {
      // [...]
  };

  int compare_ptrs(const void *aa, const void **bb) {
      struct S *a = *(const struct S **)aa;
      struct S *b = *(const struct S **)bb;
      // use the generic comparison function
      int cmp = compare(a, b);
      if (cmp)
          return cmp;
      // if the objects compare equal, preserve their relative order in the array
      return (a > b) - (a < b);
  }
  ```

  This will sort the array of pointers in the order determined by the `compare` function, while preserving the relative order of pointers to structures that compare identical.
- allocate a temporary array of structures
- copy the original array elements to this new array in the order of the sorted array of pointers.
- copy the temporary array back over the original array
- free the allocated arrays.

Here is a non thread safe implementation:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

static int (*compare_func)(const void *a, const void *b);

static int compare_ptrs(const void *aa, const void **bb) {
    unsigned char *a = *(const unsigned char **)aa;
    unsigned char *b = *(const unsigned char **)bb;
    // use the generic comparison function
    int cmp = (*compare)(a, b);
    if (cmp)
        return cmp;
    // if the objects compare equal, preserve their relative order in the array
    return (a > b) - (a < b);
}

int qsort_stable(void *base, size_t nmemb, size_t size,
                 int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) {
    if (nmemb > 1) {
        unsigned char **ptr_array = malloc(sizeof *array * nmemb);
        if (ptr_array == NULL)
            return -1;
        unsigned char *new_array = malloc(size * nmemb);
        if (new_array == NULL) {
            free(ptr_array);
            return -1;
        }
        unsigned char *p = base;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++, p += size) {
            ptr_array[i] = p;
        } 
        int (*compare_save)(const void *a, const void *b) = compare_func;
        compare_func = compar;
        qsort(ptr_array, nmemb, sizeof *ptr_array, compare_ptrs);
        compare_func = compare_save;
        p = new_array;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < nmemb; i++, p += size) {
            memcpy(p, ptr_array[i], size);
        } 
        memcpy(base, new_array, size * nmemb);
        free(new_array);
        free(ptr_array);
    }
    return 0;
}
```